# Can we apply same CORS settings to all the webapps in Tomcat Server?

Tags: tomcat, cors, tomcat9

Tomcat documentation here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter specifies how to use the CORS Filter.

Ideally each webapp can have its own CORS setting and hence it makes sense to add this to each webapp's respective `web.xml` .

But i am interested in knowing if i want to apply the same CORS filter settings to all the webapps in given tomcat server then can i add this filter to the tomcat server `web.xml` which is inside its `conf` directory? My intention is apply the CORS settings to all the webapps.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>https://example.com</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type, Authorization</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>custom-header-1, custom-header-2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>3600</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.request.decorate</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```